# Converting DataTable objects to custom class objects inheriting from DataTable

Tags: c#, inheritance, datatable

I want to create a class that will add some new methods helpful in using a DataTable class. I want to avoid static classes, so I created a class

```
MyDataTable : DataTable
```

and my methods there.

How can I convert DataTable objects to MyDataTable objects?
I already tried

```
MyDataTable dt2 = (MyDataTable)dt;
```

But it returns a InvalidCastException.

I know now that it doesn't work this way. But I also have no idea how can I solve this. Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: Like Time Says MyDataTable myTable = new MyDataTable(); What methods do you feel the need to add?

Comment: I noticed in my code multiple code that I would like to replace with one method. Stuff like get first row or return null if there are no rows. I tried to create static classes for those methods, but it didn't reduce the code ammount, which is my goal. If I could extend the DataTable class (in some way) to have these methods there that would help me greatly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of course it causes an `InvalidCastException` since not every `DataTable` is of type `MyDataTable`. You need to create an instance of your type:

```
MyDataTable myTable = new MyDataTable();
```

Normally i provide the most used constructors of the type i'm inheriting from. You can call the [base constructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173115%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)  from the constructor of your type. So for example:

```
public class MyDataTable : DataTable
{
    public MyDataTable(string name)
        : base(name)
    {
        // additional initialization
    }
}
```

Comment: Funny, working on an issue as a newbie, asked a question, switched project and never worked on it. Now I'm suddenly working with DataTables again, and used this solution by default. Thanks, Tim! :-)

Answer (score 1):

You can even write implicit cast for your Custom Class inherited from DataTable.

Comment: Unfortunatelty I receive an error: 'MyDataTable.implicit operator MyDataTable(System.Data.DataTable)': user-defined conversions to or from a base class are not allowed when creating an public static implicit operator MyDataTable(DataTable table).